# htaccess regex redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect from source url to target url using regex but it didn't work. Here i describe my problem -

Source URL:

http://example.com/forums/forum/lisa-goran-bygger-hus-t5075/

Target URL:

http://example.com/forums/details/lisa-goran-bygger-hus/

want to redirect without -t5075 from url.

htaccess rewrite rule is:

`RewriteRule ^/forums/forum/([a-z-]+[^-t0-9]) /forums/details/$1 [R=301,L]`

this isn't work its redirect to me -

http://example.com/forums/details/lisa-goran-bygger-hus-t5075/

Here regex online tester link -

http://www.regextester.com/?fam=97698

What i am doing wrong can someone help me out and explain about this problem.

Thanks

Comment: why down vote !! i tried last 3 hours solve out this problem  so after that i ask here. plz explain whats wrong in this question i will fix up.

Comment: Just upvoted in order to cancel *someone*'s downvote, which is not justified here (especially without any explanation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure *mod_rewrite* is enabled and `htaccess` files allowed to be executed.

Then, make sure `.htaccess` file is in root folder and look like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^forums/forum/(.+)-t[0-9]+/$ /forums/details/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Finally, try clearing your browser's cache. Indeed, your old rules could interfere. After that, it should work.

Comment: it works thanks for your help and i added regex for global detection like RewriteRule ^forums/forum/(.+)-(t[0-9]*) /forums/details/$1/ [R=301,L]